# MySQL deleting records that only exist in child table/cakephp update?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have two Myisam tables, let's say Parent and Child. Parent is created in a perl script. Parent is where the child gets the information(Not for editing) that's all the same, while Child holds information unique to it. Following Cakephp naming conventions, they're connected through the Parent's id field and the child's parent_id. When the Parent table is updated through another application(A record being added via Perl) it shows up in Child but if a record is deleted, Child doesn't update. Is there a way following cakephp conventions to have the table update(Removing the record that was deleted in Parent)?
I do have 'dependent' => true in the parent table for the child? Does that need to be in the child table? Or does that not matter since the table is updated outside of the app?

If nothing else, I can maybe set up a cron job to check the tables periodically, but i'm not sure how to find/delete the records in the child table that no longer exist in the Parent table via **MYSQL**. A combination of joins and where such n such <>? So my question(s) are can i do it with cakephp if the table is updated outside of the app? Or how would I do it with mysql?

Code:

```
<?php
class Drug extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Drug';
  var $order = "Drug.generic ASC";
  var $useDbConfig = 'default';
  var $actsAs = array('ExtendAssociations', 'Containable');

  var $hasOne = array(
    'FrenchTranslation' => array(
        'className' => 'FrenchTranslation',
        'dependent' => true
    ),
    'GermanTranslation' => array(
        'className' => 'GermanTranslation',
        'dependent' => true
    ),
    'SpanishTranslation' => array(
        'className' => 'SpanishTranslation',
        'dependent' => true
    )
  );
}
?>

<?php
class FrenchTranslation extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'FrenchTranslation';
    var $validate = array(
          'drug_id'=>array(
         'The drug_id must be unique.'=>array(
            'rule'=>'isUnique',
            'message'=>'The Drug ID must be unique.',
            'on'=>'create'
          ),
          'The drug_id must be numeric.'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('numeric'),
            'message'=>'The Drug ID must be numeric.'
          )
      ),
      'id'=>array(
          'The id must be unique.'=>array(
            'rule'=>'isUnique',
            'message'=>'The ID must be unique.',
            'on'=>'create'
          ),
          'The id must be numeric.'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('numeric'),
            'message'=>'The ID must be numeric.'            
          )
      )
  );

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Drug' => array(
            'className' => 'Drug',
            'foreignKey' => 'drug_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    'User'=>array(
      'className'=>'User',
      'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
    ),
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show your model relationships?

Comment: @jeremyharris Updated the post with my model code? If that's not what you meant, let me know.

Comment: This looks right. How are you deleting it, with `$this->Drug->delete()`? Because that should delete all associated FrenchTranslation, GermanTranslation and SpanishTranslation records.

Comment: The record of the parent table(drugs) is deleted by another application written in perl, which is why I wondered if it would even be possible to do simply in cakephp and why I asked about mysql as well. I can go in through my apps side and delete the record from the child table, but that means it'll have to be removed twice? Once in the perl script written by another programmer to remove the record in parent, and once again to make sure the child, french_translation is up to date.

Comment: AHHHHH that would be good information to know. Either the perl script should call an action in your app so you have control over what's deleted, or the perl script should know to delete the children. If neither of those are options, sounds like a regular CRON cleaning is in order.

Comment: @jeremyharris I'll edit it and add that little tidbit. XD It's a giant monster of an application and is rather important. I know very little about perl so i'm hesitant to make changes. Would you know the sql to check for/delete records in the child table that aren't in the parent?

Comment: Okay, cool. I posted a find call (along with pure SQL just in case) that might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little find call you can use to get all orphaned child records:

```
$this->Drug->FrenchTranslation->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('id'),
  'conditions' => array(
    'Drug.id' => null
  ),
  'contain' => array(
    'Drug' => array(
      'fields' => array('id')
    )
  )
));
```

This should call a SQL command like this

```
SELECT `FrenchTranslation`.`id`, `Drug`.`id` 
FROM `french_translations` AS FrenchTranslation
LEFT JOIN `drugs` AS `Drug` ON (`Drug`.`id` = `FrenchTranslation`.`drug_id`)
WHERE `Drug`.`id` IS NULL
```

This will return all orphaned child records, which you can then iterate through and delete. You will have to do it for each child.

Comment: Did exactly what I was looking for! Now to go write this script for cron. :D